# WooCommerce: change the style of "add to cart" button in a widget

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to add a nice and small button "add to cart" to the product displayed by WooCommerce Products Widget.

I have copied **`content-widget-product.php`** to my child theme (Storefront based) and tried 2 ways:

- First : **`echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.$product_id.'"]');`**
- And also : **`woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();`**

But either way, the result is ugly : I get a huge "add to cart" button that is as wide as my page:

[image: screenshot here:]

I would like to get a much smaller button, aligned with the picture of the item.

Something like that:
[image: [Something like that:]

I guess I should change some CSS but I don't know how...
Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead doing something on woocommerce core file .just add class in your style.css file with (.add_to_cart_button) and (.single_add_to_cart_button)

and add css as you want.

for more information you can visit this link.
https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2016/05/change-style-add-cart-button-woocommerce/

I hope it will help you.:)

Answer (score 0):

yes this can be done with CSS. Can you at least put the link of your website so I can give you an example of what you need to do?